# Set column value based on regex in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to fill a column value (col) of a table in PostgreSQL 11.0 based on values in entry_id column.

```
entry_id   col
hsa_0001
hsa_0002
rno_4894
mmu_7890
```

I am using following query:

```
try:
    connect_str = "dbname='xx' user='xx' host='xx' " "password='xx' port = xx"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connect_str)
except:
    print("Unable to connect to the database") 

query = "UPDATE tbl
             SET col = (CASE 
                        WHEN entry_id ilike '%hsa' THEN 'homo sapiens'
                        WHEN entry_id ilike '%rno' THEN 'rattus norvegicus'
                        ELSE 'mus musculus'
                        END); "

cursor.execute( query )
#print (query)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
cursor.close()
```

The expected output is:

```
entry_id   col
hsa_0001   homo_sapiens
hsa_0002   homo_sapiens
rno_4894   rattus norvegicus
mmu_7890   mus musculus
```

I am getting error while running the above query. How can I achieve the above expected output.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard specification is backwards. You specified " ilike '%hsa". This translates into "find all values without regard to case or length that *end* with hsa". What you are looking for is "find all values without regard to case or length that begins with hsa". that then is " ilike 'hsa%". So

```
query = "UPDATE tbl
             SET col = (CASE 
                        WHEN entry_id ilike 'hsa%' THEN 'homo sapiens'
                        WHEN entry_id ilike 'rno%' THEN 'rattus norvegicus'
                        ELSE 'mus musculus'
                        END); "
```